# Is this a ruby math function bug - log?

Tags: ruby, math

It should return true of following code. However, it returns false.

```
(Math.log 1000, 10) == (Math.log10 1000)
==>false
```

Is this a bug of the ruby(2.0) log function?

Comment: "Is this a language / compiler bug?" --> 99.99% of the time, the answer is No.

Comment: == is tricky at best when you're dealing with floating point.

Comment: So how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make floating point comparisons work is to define a 'close enough', such as within 0.001 or whatever you're comfortable with, and then do something like

```
delta = 0.001
log_1 = Math.log 1000, 10
log_2 = Math.log10 1000

close_enough = (log1 - log2).abs < delta
```

Comment: Float numbers comparison usually use Float::EPSILON, which seems not suitable in this case. Why?

Comment: On my machine, the difference between the two log operations is roughly double the EPSILON value.  I couldn't say whether or not ruby makes sure that you'll always get the same result or if it's just relying on whatever the machine's floating point processor gives it.  As for why two operations that are mathematically equivalent are yielding slightly different values, well, that's floating point for you.

Comment: It has a difference 4.440892098500626e-16, which is less than (2 + 1e-15) * Float::EPSILON on my machine. Thus, they should be considered equally.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> Math.log10 1000
=> 3.0
irb(main):002:0> Math.log 1000, 10
=> 2.9999999999999996
```

As you can see, `Math.log` is imprecise because of how floating point works.

If you want more information about floating point, you could just go to http://floating-point-gui.de/ or search Google.